# Efficient algorithm to count the numbers in range [L,R] that are divisible by at least one prime number in range [1,N]

Tags: python, algorithm, math, range, primes

Given N, L and R, I have to find the count of numbers in range [L,R] that are divisible by at least one prime number in range [1,N].

Constraints:

```
1<=N<=50
1<=L,R<=10^18
```

Example:

```
N=5
L=1
R=10
```

Answer = 8

Explanation:

Prime numbers in range [1,5] are {2,3,5}.
The numbers in range [1,10] that are divisible by at least one of the primes in {2,3,5} are {2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10}.

My code in Python is giving "Time Limit Exceeded" error as the constraints are too high!

My Code:

```
import math
def primes_till_n(n):
    sieve=[True]*n
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)
    return [2]+[i for i in xrange(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]

n,l,r=map(int,raw_input().split())
primes=primes_till_n(n+1)
ct=0
for i in xrange(l,r+1):
    for j in primes:
        if i%j==0:
            ct+=1
            break
print ct
```

This question is from Globalsoft hiring challenge, Hackerearth and the challenge is over now and the editorial is not provided!

Comment: Show us your code! Is this a challenge? If yes do you expect us to solve it for you without even showing your own attempts?

Comment: Can you please share the problem link? Just to make sure that this is not a running contest.

Comment: See here for the exact opposite of this question: https://github.com/niklasb/contest-algos/blob/master/number_theory.cpp#L90 This is a basic application of the  inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Code added. The contest is over and the editorial is not provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let primes array contain primes number less than 50. Size of primes array will be 15. You can calculate how many numbers in interval [L,R] are divisible by a number with O(1) complexity(calculateInterval function in code below). So you should do the same for every necessary prime number. But you should perform inclusion-exclusion for correct result. Complexity is O(2^P). P is number of prime numbers not greater than N. 2^P will be 2^15 at max.

```
    N, L, R, = map(int,raw_input().split())

    def calculateInterval(begin,end,number):
        return (end/number) - ((begin-1)/number)

    primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]

    end = 0
    while end < 15:
        if primes[end] > N:
            break
        end += 1

    res = 0
    i = 1
    while i < (1<<end):

        cnt = 0
        num = 1

        for j in xrange(end):
            if (1<<j) & i:
                cnt += 1
                num *= primes[j]

        if cnt%2 == 1:
            res += calculateInterval(L,R,num)
        else:
            res -= calculateInterval(L,R,num)

        i += 1

    print res
```